# Howto test passivation of stateful session beans in integration test (OpenEjb)?

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0, openejb

I am using OpenEjb local server (3.1.4) in my integration tests (@LocalClient annotated test classes).

```
@LocalClient
public class BoxDaoTest{

    @EJB
    private BoxDao boxDao;
    ...
}
```

BoxDao ist a stateful session bean. Ist it possible to trigger passivation of BoxDao in OpenEjb to test it in the integration test?

Answer (score 5):

You can create/configure the Stateful container in the `InitialContext` properties you use to boot OpenEJB in the tests case.

These settings will do the trick:

```
final Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("MyStatefulContainer", "new://Container?type=STATEFUL");
p.put("MyStatefulContainer.Capacity", "0");
p.put("MyStatefulContainer.Frequency", "0");

p.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.core.LocalInitialContextFactory");
final InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(properties);
//lookup your beans from the initialContext
```

This will cause the `@Stateful` bean to essentially never reside in memory, it will be read from disk and written back to disk on each method invocation or lifecycle callback.

The same thing can be done with the EJB 3.1 `javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer` API:

```
final Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("MyStatefulContainer", "new://Container?type=STATEFUL");
p.put("MyStatefulContainer.Capacity", "0");
p.put("MyStatefulContainer.Frequency", "0");

final EJBContainer container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(p);
Foo foo = (Foo) container.getContext().lookup("java:global/yourapp/yourbean");
```