# Testing Passivation with Java EE 6 (JBoss 7.x)

Tags: integration-testing, java-ee-6, jboss7.x, cdi, jboss-arquillian

I have a few SessionScoped beans that I would like to test and it occurred to me that I am not testing what happens when they get passivated.

I would very much like to resolve this gap within the integration testing. However, there doesn't seem to be easy to find documentation on this.

I have found a question with regards to [how to do with OpenEJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297364/howto-test-passivation-of-stateful-session-beans-in-integration-test-openejb) but I don't think that'll work for me.

Ideally, I would like a platform independent way that works with Arquillian but I will settle for something that'll work with JBoss 7.x.

Comment: What do you intend to test upon bean passivation? The JBoss AS 7 test suite does have [a test](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/blob/master/testsuite/integration/basic/src/test/java/org/jboss/as/test/integration/ejb/stateful/passivation/PassivationSucceedsUnitTestCase.java) that could help you, but I'm not entirely sure if that would help. It would require configuring the passivation store `max-size` and/or `idle-timeout` values.

Comment: I have a session scoped bean which contains some data. Some of these are defined as transient and I would like to test this does not break the bean on use after passivation.

Comment: Did you need to test the passivation/reactivation process or the process within JBoss AS 7? If just the former, then use the serialization/deserialization functionality within Java EE 6. If the latter, then that is a harder thing to do and you will have to come up with some good reasons why you don't trust JBoss AS 7.

Comment: I would like to test that the fields that I have marked as transient does not break the bean when it is reactivated...